# Redux deprecated code (thunk middleware related)

Tags: reactjs, middleware, redux-toolkit

I found a 3-year-old tutorial on youtube and it contains the following code snippet:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from '@redux-devtools/extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store;
```

I cannot undeprecate this code. Here I believe the only deprecated part is `applyMiddleware` but maybe also more things.

I tried to fix with something like the following:

```
import { ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk';
import { configureStore, Middleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const middleware: Middleware[] = [thunk as ThunkMiddleware];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(middleware),
});
```

Which still does not work because of this part: `[thunk as ThunkMiddleware]`

Which gives me this error:

```
Conversion of type 'typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")' to type 'ThunkMiddleware' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")' provides no match for the signature '(api: MiddlewareAPI<ThunkDispatch<any, undefined, AnyAction>, any>): (next: (action: unknown) => unknown) => (action: unknown) => unknown'.ts(2352)
```

I also tried this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';


const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(thunk),
});

export default store;
```

But `middleware:` gives me this error:

```
Type '(getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware<any>) => Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>, typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")]>' is not assignable to type '(getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware<any>) => Tuple<Middlewares<any>>'.
  Type 'Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>, typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")]>' is not assignable to type 'Tuple<Middlewares<any>>'.
    Type '[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>, typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")]' is not assignable to type 'Middlewares<any>'.
      Type 'ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction> | typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>'.
        Type 'typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>'.
          Type 'typeof import("/home/user/project/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")' provides no match for the signature '(api: MiddlewareAPI<Dispatch<UnknownAction>, any>): (next: (action: unknown) => unknown) => (action: unknown) => unknown'.ts(2322)
configureStore.d.ts(25, 5): The expected type comes from property 'middleware' which is declared here on type 'ConfigureStoreOptions<any, UnknownAction, Tuple<Middlewares<any>>, Tuple<[StoreEnhancer<{ dispatch: {}; }>, StoreEnhancer]>, any>'
(property) ConfigureStoreOptions<any, UnknownAction, Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>]>, Tuple<[StoreEnhancer<{ dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, undefined, UnknownAction>; }>, StoreEnhancer]>, any>.middleware?: ((getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware<any>) => Tuple<[thunk.ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>]>) | undefined
An array of Redux middleware to install, or a callback receiving getDefaultMiddleware and returning a Tuple of middleware. If not supplied, defaults to the set of middleware returned by getDefaultMiddleware().

@example

`middleware: (gDM) => gDM().concat(logger, apiMiddleware, yourCustomMiddleware)`
@see — https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#intended-usage
```

Comment: Redux-Toolkit's default middleware already includes the Thunk middleware enabled by default, there's no need to import it and add it, it's already there.

Comment: Same with the redux devtools. It's automatically injected in development mode, so there's no need for custom code to add it.

Comment: Also one issue in your example is because you need to spread middlewares, eg `getDefaultMiddleware().concat(...middleware)` in order to add each individual element instead of one array element.

Comment: I wanted to add that on top of all of that, three years ago your tutorial was already very outdated. Redux Toolkit is the officially recommended way of writing any Redux logic since 2019. Please follow the official Redux tutorial instead: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts